# How to use Triple_DES algorithm in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, tripledes

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION
BY PASSWORD = 'abcdefg'
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
WITH SUBJECT = 'FirstCertificateBYShashank'
GO
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SYM_TDES_FOR_IDS
WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
GO
```

When I am trying to run this I got the below error

**Incorrect syntax near 'TRIPLE_DES'**

Comment: You don't, because it's broken. It was broken 20 years ago. The docs have a very strong warning against its use

Comment: check the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-symmetric-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 on the `Warning`

Comment: In fact the docs contain a strong warning against its use and explain it's deprecated and you need to downgrade the database compatibility version to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with SQL Server 2016 (13.x), all algorithms other than AES_128, AES_192, and AES_256 are deprecated. To use older algorithms (not recommended) you must set the database to database compatibility level 120 or lower.

See more information here [Choose an Encryption Algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/choose-an-encryption-algorithm)